# Refactoring arrays and sub-arrays based on variable value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

What is a good syntaxic manner to handle the following array structure and create database records in rails, according to an instance variable?

It is quite obvious that such a structure becomes unwieldly very quickly...

```
if @event.persons_per_unit == "2"
  if @event.number_units == "1"
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['surname'])
  elsif @event.number_units == "2"
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['surname'])
  elsif @event.number_units == "3"
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][1]['surname'])
  elsif @event.number_units == "4"
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][0]['persons'][1]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][1]['persons'][1]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][2]['persons'][1]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][3]['persons'][0]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][3]['persons'][0]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][3]['persons'][0]['surname'])
    @entiti = Entiti.create(event_id: @event.id,
      type: @r['items'][0]['units'][3]['persons'][1]['type'], 
      first_name: @r['items'][0]['units'][3]['persons'][1]['first_name'], 
      surname: @r['items'][0]['units'][3]['persons'][1]['surname'])
  else
```

Comment: What does `@r` look like? That wall of code is a little noisy, might be easier to start with the data. Also, where does the data come from and can you change that to be more convenient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like (unless I'm misreading things) you probably just want a couple of loops. Something along the lines of:

```
@r['items'].each do |item|
  item['units'].each do |unit|
    unit['persons'].each do |person|
      # if `slice` is available, otherwise just create the hash as you've done
      # using `person` instead of the long nested chain
      Entiti.create(person.slice('type', 'first_name', 'surname').
        merge(event_id: @event.id))
    end
  end
end
```

if you're worried about things like `@event.persons_per_unit == 2` and then having 3 person records in a unit hash, you could use `take`:

```
unit['persons'].take(@event.persons_per_unit.to_i).each do |person|
  # ...
end
```

Same for number of units, if there's a maximum number of units allowed (say, you can't have more than 4, but you are worried you might have 5 in `@r['items']`. If these are concerns for you, I'd recommend tying an `Entiti` to the `Event` (via a `has_many`) and setting up model validations to make sure things are in line. If the `Event` model has a `has_many` already, you could also just `@event.entitis.create(...)` (not sure how that'll pluralize)

Also, you keep reassigning `@entiti`, and only the last one will stick, you might want an array if you need all instances later, otherwise no need to store it at all.

Comment: `slice` turned out to be unavailable. Great pointer on controlling the creation limited to instance variable values